# Change to custom background when a cell is highlighted

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, background

How can I change the background of a custom cell when a it is selected ?

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```

use this

Comment: thanks, it preserves me from subclassing the cell. I didn't know that there were a selectedBagroundView

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass `UITableViewCell`, and override the following methods:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

You can change the cell's background image there.

The cell's `selectionStyle` property allows for some very basic customization, too.